# Como cambiar el css de mi child theme electro en Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Quesiera cambiar los valores hexadecimales de una parte del css de mi web

[www.xiaomimportperu.com](http://www.xiaomimportperu.com)

El naranja que hay en la web lo necesito de un color mas oscuro, como lo puedo hacer?

Esta corriendo con el child theme

Answer (score 0):

Para ello tendrás que inspeccionar el elemento que quieres cambiar, por ejemplo, ve a la barra naranja que esta en el footer, da click derecho inspeccionar y busca el objeto que tiene el color naranja, cambia el color por algún otro y pon ese código css en los estilos de tu child theme o bien en apariencia -> CSS Personalizado, para la barra seria este código.

```
#payment .place-order button[type=submit], .aws-container .aws-search-form .aws-search-clear, .button:hover::before, .category-icons-carousel .category a:hover .category-icon, .columns-6-1>ul.products.product-main-6-1>li.product .electro-wc-product-gallery .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active, .da .da-action>a::after, .da-block .da-action::after, .deal-products-with-featured header, .deal-products-with-featured ul.products>li.product.product-featured .savings, .deal-progress .progress-bar, .demo_store, .departments-menu-v2-title, .dokan-elector-style-active.store-v1 .profile-frame+.dokan-store-tabs>ul li.active a:after, .dokan-elector-style-active.store-v5 .profile-frame+.dokan-store-tabs>ul li.active a:after, .ec-tabs>li.active a::before, .electro-handheld-footer-bar ul li a .count, .electro-navbar, .electro-navbar-primary, .footer-newsletter, .full-color-background .header-v3, .full-color-background .header-v4, .full-color-background .top-bar, .handheld-header-v2, .handheld-header-v2.stuck, .handheld-navigation-wrapper .stuck .navbar-toggler, .handheld-navigation-wrapper .stuck button, .handheld-navigation-wrapper.toggled .stuck .navbar-toggler, .handheld-navigation-wrapper.toggled .stuck button, .header-icon-counter, .header-v1 .navbar-search .input-group .btn, .header-v3 .navbar-search .input-group .btn, .header-v5, .header-v5 .header-top, .header-v5 .stuck, .header-v6 .navbar-search .input-group .btn, .header-v7 .masthead, .header-v8 .navbar-search .input-group .btn, .home-mobile-v2-features-block, .mobile-header-v2, .mobile-header-v2.stuck, .navbar-compare .count, .navbar-mini-cart .cart-items-count, .navbar-primary, .navbar-search-input-group .navbar-search-button, .navbar-wishlist .count, .owl-dots .owl-dot.active, .owl-item .product:hover .added_to_cart::before, .owl-item .product:hover .button::before, .pace .pace-progress, .pagination ul.page-numbers>li a.current, .pagination ul.page-numbers>li span.current, .product-categories-list-with-header.v2 header .caption .section-title, .products-2-1-2 .nav-link.active::before, .products-2-1-2 .nav-link:hover::before, .products-4-1-4 .nav-link.active::before, .products-4-1-4 .nav-link:hover::before, .products-6-1 header.show-nav ul.nav .nav-item.active .nav-link, .products-carousel-banner-vertical-tabs .banners-tabs>.nav a.active, .products-carousel-tabs .nav-link.active::before, .products-carousel-tabs-v5 header ul.nav-inline .nav-link.active, .products-carousel-tabs-with-deal header ul.nav-inline .nav-link.active, .products-carousel-with-timer .deal-countdown-timer, .products.show-btn>li.product .added_to_cart, .products.show-btn>li.product .button, .section-onsale-product .savings, .section-onsale-product-carousel .onsale-product-carousel .onsale-product .onsale-product-content .deal-cart-button .added_to_cart, .section-onsale-product-carousel .onsale-product-carousel .onsale-product .onsale-product-content .deal-cart-button .button, .section-onsale-product-carousel .savings, .show-nav .nav .nav-item.active .nav-link, .single-product .product-images-wrapper .electro-wc-product-gallery .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active, .single-product .product-images-wrapper .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active, .single-product .product-images-wrapper .woocommerce-product-gallery.electro-carousel-loaded .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active, .single_add_to_cart_button, .vertical-menu>li:first-child, .wc-tabs>li.active a::before, .widget.widget_tag_cloud .tagcloud a:focus, .widget.widget_tag_cloud .tagcloud a:hover, .widget_electro_products_carousel_widget .section-products-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next:hover, .widget_electro_products_carousel_widget .section-products-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover, .widget_price_filter .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle, .woocommerce-info, .woocommerce-noreviews, .woocommerce-pagination ul.page-numbers>li a.current, .woocommerce-pagination ul.page-numbers>li span.current, .wpb-accordion .vc_tta.vc_general .vc_tta-panel.vc_active .vc_tta-panel-heading .vc_tta-panel-title>a i, .yith-wcqv-button, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form .wpforms-page-button, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form button[type=submit], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=submit], li.product:hover .added_to_cart::before, li.product:hover .button::before, p.no-comments, section .deals-carousel-inner-block .onsale-product .onsale-product-content .deal-cart-button .added_to_cart, section .deals-carousel-inner-block .onsale-product .onsale-product-content .deal-cart-button .button, ul.products>li.product.list-view.list-view-small .button:active::after, ul.products>li.product.list-view.list-view-small .button:focus::after, ul.products>li.product.list-view.list-view-small .button:hover::after, ul.products>li.product.list-view:not(.list-view-small) .button:active, ul.products>li.product.list-view:not(.list-view-small) .button:focus, ul.products>li.product.list-view:not(.list-view-small) .button:hover, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-1>li.product .product-loop-footer .button, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-2>li.product .product-loop-footer .button, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-3>li.product .product-loop-footer .button, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-4>li.product .product-loop-footer .button, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-5>li.product .product-loop-footer .button, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-6>li.product .product-loop-footer .button, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-7>li.product .product-loop-footer .button, ul.products[data-view=list-view].columns-8>li.product .product-loop-footer .button {
    background-color: #000!important;
}
```

La línea `background-color: #000!important;` cambia el color de fondo a negro, y se usa el `!important` para hace que ignore cualquier otra instrucción que trate de cambiar el color.

Aun así la mayoría de temas permiten modificar el color de manera dinamica, búscalo en ajustes o alguna parte del menú de administración o bien en apariencia -> personalizar, talvez haya algún lugar ahí para hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás trabajando con Child Themes puedes poner el estilo nuevo en el CSS de tu child theme. Incluso es mejor que por motivos de rendimiento lo coloques allí en vez de hacerlo en "apariencia -> CSS Personalizado" ya que eso genera mas consultas a la base de datos lo cual afecta los tiempos de carga.